# Comma in property files

Tags: java, properties

```
custc.krtdocument.errors=/properties/error.properties,20
```

I found this in one of the property files in my java web project, I wonder In above what is the meaning of putting ",20" there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indicates list of values or Lists and arrays

Using ',' Commons Configuration has the ability to return easily a list of values. For example a properties file can contain a list of comma separated values

```
colors.pie = #FF0000, #00FF00, #0000FF
```

**Using Java properties class**

```
  private String[] errs = prop.getProperty("custc.krtdocument.errors").split[","];
```

Answer (score 1):

It usually indicates that `custc.krtdocument.errors` will be an array type

```
@Value("${custc.krtdocument.errors}")
private String[] errors;
```